# How to make php code with html on neovim with correct indentation, syntax highlighting and autocomplete?

Tags: php, html, neovim

I'm getting started with php development, and as neovim is my go-to code editor, I would like to use it for that as well. Problem is, identation and autocomplete just don't work, even with me using intelliphense with mason and lsp-zero. Is there something I can do?

Just to illustrate, the code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo "<p>PHP is working!</p>";
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
echo '<p>Hello ' . $_GET['name'] . '</p>';
}
else {
echo '<p>Hello World</p:;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And I want it like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo "<p>PHP is working!</p>";
      if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
        echo '<p>Hello ' . $_GET['name'] . '</p>';
      }
      else {
        echo '<p>Hello World</p:;
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usually, you should avoid to mix PHP and HTML like that. Also, be warned that your code is highly vulnerable to XSS injection

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the LSP server is not attached to the buffer; you can check it with `:LspInfo`.